# multiplying through multiple tuple elements inside a list to find the minimum value using lambda, filter and map functions

Tags: python, filter, list-comprehension, reduce

```
from functools import reduce

orders = [ [1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274",18,12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)]], 
           [2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
           [3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
           [4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733",11,18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)] ]

print(list(map(lambda x: [x[0]] + list(map(lambda y: (y[0], y[1]*y[2]), x[1:])), orders)))
```

I have been trying to figure out lambda, filter, and map. I came to a halt where I wanted to try and multiply the integers in the second element i.e (4 & 9.99), (18 & 12.99), (9 & 44.95) etc. Then find the minimum value for each element and have the output accordingly.

I know I can use min(), but I have no idea how to implement it, also my current output is a 2d-list where expected out is tuples inside a list. I understand I need to use a for loop to iteratitate through the tuples elements once I multiply them.

Current output:

```
[[1, ('5464', 39.96), ('8274', 233.82), ('9744', 404.55)], [2, ('5464', 89.91), ('9744', 404.55)], [3, ('5464', 89.91), ('88112', 274.89)], [4, ('8732', 83.93), ('7733', 208.89), ('88112', 199.75)]]
```

Wanted output:

```
[(1,"5464"), (2,"5464"), (3,"5464"), (4,"8732")]
```

So the question would be, how do I implement the min() function to filter out the minimum product of index[1] & index[2] in the tuples of a nested list.

(Sorry for bad english, I tried my best).

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```py
result = list(map(lambda order: (order[0], min(order[1:], key=lambda o: o[1] * o[2])[0]), orders))
```

But I would replace `map` with a list comprehension:

```py
result = [(no, min(order, key=lambda o: o[1] * o[2])[0]) for no, *order in orders]
```

Both result in:

```py
[(1, '5464'), (2, '5464'), (3, '5464'), (4, '8732')]
```

Comment: Thank you, is "key=lambda" here sorting through the tuples?

Comment: @EggCoder Yes. key-functions are pretty common in contexts which are based on comparisons (sorting relies heavily on comparisons). With a key-function the comparisons are done based on the values of the key-function instead of the original items. For example the builtin `sorted` function allows for a key-function, as well as `list.sort`, `itertools.groupby`, since Python 3.10 the `bisect` module, a lot of function from the `heapq` module, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
orders = [[1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274",18,12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)], 
          [2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
          [3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
          [4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733",11,18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)]]

products = [[_order[1]*_order[2] for _order in _order_list[1:]] for _order_list in orders]

min_product_address = [(i, _product.index(min(_product)) + 1) for i, _product in enumerate(products)]

output = [(orders[i][0], orders[i][j][0]) for i, j in min_product_address]

[(1, '5464'), (2, '5464'), (3, '5464'), (4, '8732')]
```

or

```
orders = [[1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274",18,12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)], 
          [2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
          [3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
          [4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733",11,18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)]]

output = []
for _order_list in orders:
    _order_min_i = 1
    _order_min = _order_list[_order_min_i][1] * _order_list[_order_min_i][2]
    for i in range(2, len(_order_list)):
        _product = _order_list[i][1] * _order_list[i][2] 
        if _product < _order_min:
            _order_min = _product
            _order_min_i = i
    output.append((_order_list[0], _order_list[_order_min_i][0]))

[(1, '5464'), (2, '5464'), (3, '5464'), (4, '8732')]
```

Comment: Thank you, Would you care to show this using lambda, map and filter?

Comment: Coudn't think of a more efficient way than the proposed using specifically map, filter, lambda:)